# Can I configure tinyproxy to limit the outbound hosts?

Tags: linux, configuration, proxy

So using the "allow" command . . . I can limit which systems on my Intranet are allowed to use my proxy . . . this much is working.

However, beyond that I want to limit what hosts those systems can use.  In my case for instance I want to allow the use of any of the Jenkins download sites/mirrors, but I don't want to allow access to anything else . . . all non-Jenkins related requests should be rejected.

I suspect the answer is in the "upstream" command, but just don't know enough about proxies to understand the docs.

The question is simple, if I want my tinyproxy to allow connections to "abc.com" and "xyz.com" ONLY, how do I configure tinyproxy to allow only those request through?

Frank

Answer (score 1):

When I was reviewing the tinyproxy.conf docs, I completely overlooked a section on "filters".  It is possible to configure tinyproxy to refused to forward all traffic, except traffic that matches a file full of regular expressions (or visa versa).

I have not actually done this yet, but the docs look straight forward and easy to understand.  I'll implement it tomorrow at work.